# Scheduling events in a WSGI framework

Tags: python, wsgi, schedule

I've written a Python app that reads a database of tasks, and schedule.enter()s those tasks at various intervals.  Each task reschedules itself as it executes.

I'd like to integrate this app with a WSGI framework, so that tasks can be added or deleted in response to HTTP requests.  I assume I could use XML-RPC to communicate between the framework process and the task engine, but I'd like to know if there's a framework that has built-in event scheduling which can be modified via HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you really want is something like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/). It's a Python-based distributed task queue which has various task behaviours including [periodic and crontab](http://celeryq.org/docs/getting-started/periodic-tasks.html).

Prior to version 2.0, it had a dependency on Django, but that has now been reduced to an integration plugin.